# How Can I Push My Ruby/Rails App To Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, aws-cloud9

I'm very new to software programming, so bear with me. I'm taking an online web development course that uses Ruby on Rails via AWS on Cloud9. I've gotten to a point in the course where it's time to push my program to Heroku, but it's not working. As you'll see in the code I attached below, it states "The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist: ruby-2.3.0." It's an old version of Ruby, so that's understandable. It's an old course, after all.

Naturally, I tried to install a more updated version of Ruby (Ruby 2.7.6) in my virtual workstation, and I received confirmation from my command line that it had installed successfully. Or so I thought. After attempting to deploy the code again to Heroku, I received the same notification - that Ruby 2.3.0 doesn't exist. But I thought I had updated my Ruby version? Meanwhile, I cannot continue the course until this is resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
ec2-user:~/environment/saasapp (master) $ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 15518, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15518/15518), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (8189/8189), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15518/15518), 38.29 MiB | 42.71 MiB/s, done.
Total 15518 (delta 5945), reused 15518 (delta 5945), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist: ruby-2.3.0
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 0c41dc02b467640a074f0ffcb8c93cf034e44fad
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 0c41dc02b467640a074f0ffcb8c93cf034e44fad
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to secret-shelf-76327.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/secret-shelf-76327.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secret-shelf-76327.git'
```

Comment: Do you have specified version in `Gemfile` or `.ruby-version`?

Comment: You *did* push to heroku: Git gathered your commits and sent them to Heroku. *Heroku* then *rejected* them, for reasons that Heroku explains with those `remote: !` lines. Read those and address them. Git isn't involved in the acceptance or rejection here, it just passes it through.

Answer (score 0):

The rails version you are currently working in and the rails version present in your `bin/rails` file is different. you just need to regenerate the binstubs file with your local ruby version.

Run this command to regenerate your bundler file.
`bundle binstubs bundler --force`

for more info refer the doc here.
https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define the ruby version in the Gemfile itself.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.6.5"
```

Add these lines at the top of your Gemfile and do a `bundle install` again.